# Why can't my lexicographic program print all three strings?

Tags: java

As you can see I have three names below called: s1, s2, and s3. It should put the in alpha order on a new line but "Ashley" is not printing. `enter code here`

```
public class Lex {
static String s1 = "Ashley";
static String s2 = "Joe";
static String s3  = "John";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String topString = "";
        String midString = "";
        String botString = "";

         if (s1.compareTo(s2) > 0 && (s1.compareTo(s3) > 0)) {
            topString = s1; }
            else if (s1.compareTo(s2) < 0 && (s1.compareTo(s3) > 0)) {
            midString = s1; }
                else{ botString = s1; }

         if (s2.compareTo(s1) > 0 && (s2.compareTo(s3) > 0)) {
            topString = s2; }
            else if (s2.compareTo(s1) < 0 && (s2.compareTo(s3) > 0)) {
            midString = s2; }
                else { botString = s2; }

         if (s3.compareTo(s2) > 0 && (s3.compareTo(s1) > 0)) {
            topString = s3; }
            else if (s3.compareTo(s2) < 0 && (s3.compareTo(s1) > 0)) {
            midString = s3; }
            else { botString = s3;}

            System.out.println(topString);
            System.out.println(midString); 
            System.out.println(botString);
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're reinventing the wheel. Use `Arrays.sort` or `Collections.sort`

Comment: @4castle I am supposed to do it this way. I know it is way easier to do arrays but I have to do it this way for class because, "We haven't learned arrays yet."

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Answer (score 0):

You are complicating the logic as you are trying to compare too many things at a time which will make understanding & reading the logic becomes be harder (also your code indentation is not good).

You can try the below code with inline comments which will take the step by step comparisons and achieve the result.

```
             if(s1.compareTo(s2) < 0) { //is s1 higher than s2 ?
                if(s1.compareTo(s3) < 0) { //is s1 higher than s3 as well ?
                    topString = s1;//then topper is s1
                    if(s2.compareTo(s3) < 0) {//is s2 higher than s3 ?
                        midString = s2;//then mid is s2 
                        botString = s3;//bot is s3
                    }
                } else {
                    topString = s3;//s3 is topper compared to s1 and s2
                    midString = s1;//mid is s1
                    botString = s2;//bot is s2
                }
             } else {//means s2 is topper
                if(s2.compareTo(s3) < 0) {//is s2 topper than s3 as well ?
                    topString = s2;//yes, so s2 is topper
                    if(s1.compareTo(s3) < 0) {//is s1 or s3 who is first ?
                        midString = s1;//s1 is first, so at middle
                        botString = s3;//s3 is bot
                    }
                } else {//s2 is not topper than s3, but topper than s2
                    topString = s3;//top is s3
                    midString = s2;//mid is s2
                    botString = s1;//bot is s1
                }
            }
```